# How do I mock ES modules in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, node-modules

Say I've implemented a module as follows:

```
import { foo } from 'dep1'

export const bar = () => foo()
```

How would I mock `dep1` so I can unit test `bar`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible approach could use ES module loader hooks.

Say that `dep1` contains the working code and we want to mock it. I would create a file called `mymodule.mocks.mjs` where I would mock `foo`:

```
// Regular mymodule.mjs
import { foo } from 'dep1'

export const bar = () => foo()
```

---

```
// Mocked mymodule.mocks.mjs

// dep1.foo() returns string
export const bar = () => 'whatever'
```

Now we should be able to load `mymodule.mocks.mjs` when `mymodule.mjs` is requested during a test run.

### So we implement `testModuleLoader.mjs`

Here's a custom module loader hook that implements the `*.mocks.mjs` convention:

```
import { existsSync } from 'fs'
import { dirname, extname, basename, join } from 'path'
import { parse } from 'url'

// The 'specifier' is the name or path that we provide
// when we import a module (i.e. import { x } from '[[specifier]]')
export function resolve (
   specifier,
   parentModuleURL,
   defaultResolver
) {
   // For built-ins
   if ( !parentModuleURL )
      return defaultResolver ( specifier, parentModuleURL )

   // If the specifier has no extension we provide the
   // Michael Jackson extension as the default one
   const moduleExt = extname ( specifier ) || '.mjs'
   const moduleDir = dirname ( specifier )
   const { pathname: parentModulePath } = parse (
      parentModuleURL
   )
   const fileName = basename ( specifier, moduleExt )

   // We build the possible mocks' module file path
   const mockFilePath = join (
      dirname ( parentModulePath ),
      moduleDir,
      `${fileName}.mocks${moduleExt}`
   )

   // If there's a file which ends with '.mocks.mjs'
   // we resolve that module instead of the regular one
   if ( existsSync ( mockFilePath ) )
      return defaultResolver ( mockFilePath, parentModuleURL )

   return defaultResolver ( specifier, parentModuleURL )
}
```

### Using it

It's just about providing it to `node`:

```
node --experimental-modules --loader ./path/to/testModuleLoader.mjs ./path/to/app.mjs
```

[Learn more](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_loader_hooks) about ES module loader hooks.